# how to retrieve dictionary from firestore in c#

Tags: c#, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to retrieve data his type is map to combobox in c# but I'm failing I need help
This is my attempt

```
 async void GetSection()
    {
        DocumentReference docRef = database.Collection("Class").Document(combClasses.SelectedItem.ToString());
        DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await docRef.GetSnapshotAsync();
        if (snapshot.Exists)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("Document data for {0} document:", snapshot.Id);
            Dictionary<string, object> city = snapshot.ToDictionary();
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> pair in city)
            {
                if (pair.Key.Equals("Section"))
                {
                  
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Document {0} does not exist!", snapshot.Id);
        }           
    }
```

[my firestore data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkeTN.png)

Comment: And what is your issue ? Where are you stuck ?

Comment: i did it thank you

Comment: You solve it ? You can self-answer to share how you fix it, to help other person

Comment: yes 
ok i will share it now

Answer (score 0):

```
 DocumentReference doc = database.Collection("Class").Document(combClasses.SelectedItem.ToString());
        DocumentSnapshot snap = await doc.GetSnapshotAsync();
        if (snap.Exists)
        {
            Dictionary<string, object> data = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            foreach (var item in snap.ToDictionary())
            {
                if (item.Key == "Section")
                {
                    foreach (var sec in (Dictionary<string, object>)item.Value)
                    {
                        data.Add(sec.Key, sec.Value);
                        
                            string ss = (sec.Key.ToString() + " # of student ( " + Convert.ToString(sec.Value.ToString()) + " )");
                            combSection.Items.Add(ss);                                                       
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).